# UNIX (not Linux) password change with C

Tags: c, unix

I already know that I can read the password structure (getpwnam etc.) but how can I alter the specific password. Do I have to lock the master.passwd and modify it directly or better make a copy from master.passwd modify this and make a file move after correct modifications?

At last, I don't want to make a system(usermod ...) because that invokes the shell and should be the last solution!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the hints! My solution is now very close to the solution in OpenBSD's local_passwd.c Which uses the functions pw_lock(), pw_init() and pw_mkdb(). These functions let you also do some modifications if you're using the old passwd or the spwd.db.

Answer (score 2):

In C for Unix like Solaris or AIX , you can either :

- Use PAM API if available. Here are [some articles](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/user_auth_solaris1.html) about it on Solaris.
- Add a new password with [putpwent](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?putpwent%203)
- Change existing password with [getpwent](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?getpwent%203), [crypt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/crypt.html) your new password and finish with [endpwent](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?endpwent%203)

You'll see [here a complete sample program](http://www.opengroup.org/sud/sud1/xsh/cpasswd.c.htm) to change a pasword for unix in C using putpwent & getpwent. AIX documentation [seems to confirm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.basetechref/doc/basetrf1/getpwent.htm) it should also works on their OS.

Comment: If the passwords are stored in the `passwd` file and not shadow or equivalent, why even bother setting a password? All it does is make it so it takes 3 hours longer to login as whoever you want... ;-)